# Flexible Table Height HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a page which contains a table. On the same page, there is a footer and side bar. I've manipulated the table such that the width is how I like it, however I cannot seem to use the same method for height.

This is what my page currently looks like:

[image: table item example]

There are many more table items that continue to go down, however as you can see, the items are being cut off by the footer. When I set the height to an explicit value such as `300px` I get the effect that I am looking for:

[image: image2]

where there is a scrollbar. The problem with this is that it is not dynamic. For example, if I make the window size larger vertically, the table height is not increased with it. I've tried using % values such as `80%` but it does not seem to affect anything. I want to be able to resize the window and have the height of the table increase/decrease with the resize so that it fits over the whole screen except the footer. How can I achieve this?

**EDIT**

Here is my source code (ReactJS):

HTML

```html
<table className='task-table'>
    <tbody>
        <tr className='tasks-header'>
            <th>Store</th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Size</th>
            <th>Profile</th>
            <th>Proxies</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
        {this.renderTaskData()}
   </tbody>
</table>
```

SASS

```css
.task-table {
  margin-left: 85px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border-spacing: 0 10px;
  width: calc(100% - 107px);
  user-select: none;

  display: block;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 300px;

  tbody {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.tasks-header {
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: $extra-bold;
  color: $text-light;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-align: left;

  th {
    padding-left: 36px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you like to share your source code? Meanwhile, perhaps you should try nesting the table in a div since divs are block-level elements and then control the size of the div with % or vh. Your table should reflow according to the height of this container div.

Comment: I've tried nested divs and I seem to be having the same issue. I'm probably doing something wrong. I've added my source code. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I think I figured it out thank you. I used a nested div and used vh instead of %.